# Why cannot form reference to 'decltype(auto)'

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype

```
int main(){
    decltype(auto)&& a = 100;
}
```

The above code, an error in the GCC and Clang.

```
int main(){
    decltype(int)&& a = 100;
}
```

This code correct.

In N4296,

In the § 8.3.2/6

> If a typedef (7.1.3), a type template-parameter (14.3.1), or a decltype-specifier (7.1.6.2) denotes a type TR
>   that is a reference to a type T, an attempt to create the type “lvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type
>   “lvalue reference to T”, while an attempt to create the type “rvalue reference to cv TR” creates the type TR.

*decltype-specifier* in § 7.1.6.2

> decltype-specifier:
>   　　decltype ( expression )
>   　　decltype ( auto )

I think *§ 8.3.2/6* is a problem with the wording.

Why reference to *decltype(auto)* is not allowed. 
Please tell me the wording of the relevant standard.
Sorry in poor English.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In § 7.1.6.4 [dcl.spec.auto]

> If the placeholder is the decltype(auto) type-specifier, the declared
>   type of the variable or return type of the function **shall be the
>   placeholder alone**. The type deduced for the variable or return type is
>   determined as described in 7.1.6.2, as though the initializer had been
>   the operand of the decltype.

So this is allowed :

```
decltype(auto) a = 100;
```

But not this:

```
decltype(auto)& a = 100;
```

Or this :

```
decltype(auto)&& a = 100;
```

This makes sense, since one of the idea behind `decltype(auto)` is to preserve reference-ness during type deduction (i.e. use `decltype` type deduction, instead of template/auto type deduction)

---

The standard gives us examples as how references are deduced by `decltype(auto)` :

```
int i;
int&& f();
auto x3a = i;                  // decltype(x3a) is int
decltype(auto) x3d = i;        // decltype(x3d) is int
auto x4a = (i);                // decltype(x4a) is int
decltype(auto) x4d = (i);      // decltype(x4d) is int&
auto x5a = f();                // decltype(x5a) is int
decltype(auto) x5d = f();      // decltype(x5d) is int&&
auto x6a = { 1, 2 };           // decltype(x6a) is std::initializer_list<int>
decltype(auto) x6d = { 1, 2 }; // error, { 1, 2 } is not an expression
auto *x7a = &i;                // decltype(x7a) is int*
decltype(auto)*x7d = &i;       // error, declared type is not plain decltype(auto)
```

Comment: Thank you. §8.3.2/6 Confusing.